# How to find value of a key in a json response trace file using shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have a response trace file containing below response:

```
#RESPONSE BODY 
#--------------------
{"totalItems":1,"member":[{"name":"name","title":"PatchedT","description":"My des_","id":"70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B","type":"Product","modified":"2019 Jul 23 10:22:15","created":"2019 Jul 23 10:21:54",}]}
```

I need to fetch the value of the "id" key in a variable which I can put in my further code.

Expected result is 
`echo $id` - should give me `70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty ([don't use eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)):

```
eval $(cat response_file | tail -1 | awk -F , '{ print $5 }' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/:/=/')
```

It is based on the *exact* structure you gave, and hoping there is no `,` in any value before `"id"`.

Or assign it yourself:

```
id=$(cat response_file | tail -1 | awk -F , '{ print $5 }' | cut -d: -f2 | sed -e 's/"//g')
```

Note that you can't access the `name` field with that trick, as it is the first item of the `member` array and will be "swallowed" by the `{ print $2 }`. You can use an even-uglier hack to retrieve it though:

```
id=$(cat response_file | tail -1 | sed -e 's/:\[/,/g' -e 's/}\]//g' | awk -F , '{ print $5 }' | cut -d: -f2 | sed -e 's/"//g')
```

But, if you can, `jq` is the right tool for that work instead of ugly hacks like that (but if it works...).

Comment: i am getting a response as  "70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B" , how do i remove the ""

Comment: will the solution work if i want to get the value of "type"

Comment: @kpk1 check my edit with `sed` to remove the quote. To get value of `type`, chagne the `$5` to `$6` in `{ print $5 }`.

Comment: thanks Yes that worked for me , but it does not give me the value of "name" key

Comment: @kpk1 check my last edit, that removes the array brackets.

Comment: i have updated the response and i need to get the value of "cestamp" i tried changing the $5 to  $15 but i am getting 35638256264100006992365D71790900}] as the output

Comment: @kpk1: Don't change your question in essential parts. Rollback your last change to your question and start a new question.

Comment: i did a rollback to the question.

Comment: @kpk1 I agree with @Cyrus here. Check the change to `sed` that removes the `}\]` instead of `\]`.

Answer (score 3):

With valid JSON (remove first to second row with `sed` and parse with `jq`):

```
id=$(sed '1,2d' file | jq -r '.member[]|.id')
```

Output to variable id:

```
70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but can't use jq.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using `jq` to parse json.
But given that json is mostly compatible with python dictionaries and arrays, this HACK would work too:

```
$ cat resp
#RESPONSE BODY 
#--------------------
{"totalItems":1,"member":[{"name":"name","title":"PatchedT","description":"My des_","id":"70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B","type":"Product","modified":"2019 Jul 23 10:22:15","created":"2019 Jul 23 10:21:54",}]}

$ awk 'NR==3{print "a="$0;print "print a[\"member\"][0][\"id\"]"}' resp | python
70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B
$ sed -n '3s|.*|a=\0\nprint a["member"][0]["id"]|p' resp | python
70EA96FB313349279EB089BA9DE2EC3B
```

Note that this code is
1. dirty hack, because your system does not have the right tool - `jq`
2. susceptible to shell injection attacks. Hence use it ONLY IF you trust the response received from your service.

Comment: I upvote all answers asking for using the right tool

Answer (score 0):

When you can't use `jq`, you can consider

```
id=$(grep -Eo "[0-9A-F]{32}" file)
```

This is only working when the file looks like what I expect, so you might need to add extra checks like

```
id=$(grep "My des_" file | grep -Eo "[0-9A-F]{32}" | head -1)
```